# Advice regarding a Python function and how to replace multiple characters with different indexs

Tags: python, string, replace, bioinformatics

I recently went back to Python, and I need some help with this problem:

I have DNA sequences of equal length, and some of them have N's (errors) inside. I need a script that replaces N's in one sequence from available nucleotides from the other sequences. So, only if all the sequences that are used as input have an N in one position, the output is going to have an N.
Also, if one sequence has an N, but the other two sequences have, for example, an A and a T, there should be two outputs: one with one option, and one with another.

But this does not mean that I need all possible combinations (that would be easier). The script should 'stick' to one set of options from one sequence, not making every possibility as an output.

Here are some inputs and expected output as examples:

1. ["ATC", "CGN", "NNN"] should return [ATC, CGC]
2. ["ACG", "TGT", "CAG"] should return ["ACG", "TGT", "CAG"]
3. ["ATN", "GCN", "GGN"] should return ["ATN", "GCN", "GGN"]

All the examples above work well with my code so far.

But I am having some issues making these examples work:

1. ["ACN", "TGT", "NNG"] should return ['ACT', 'TGG', 'ACG', 'TGT']
2. ["NTA", "GNC", "CGN"] should return ["GTA", "CTA", "GGC", "GTC", "CGA"]
3. ["NNA", "CNN", "NGN"] should return ['NNA', 'CNN', 'NGN']
4. ["ACN", "TNT", "NNG"] should return  ['ACT,' 'ACG', 'TCT', 'ACG']. TCG should not be a valid option, due to 'mixing' information from two different sequences: 'ACT' and 'TNT'

These last 3 sequences are the most common in my inputs.
Here is my code so far, it is quite simple:

```
import numpy as np


def procesar_secuencias(secuencias):
    output = []
    secuencias_con_n = [s for s in secuencias if 'N' in s] # check if there are N's

    if len(secuencias_con_n) == 0: # If there are no N's, simply return the sequences as is 
        return secuencias


    a = [] # positions and nt 
    b = []

    for i in range(len(secuencias)): # for all sequences

        for j,k in  enumerate(secuencias[i]): # j is position, k is nt

          if k != 'N': # if it not an N, save the information
            a.append(k)
            b.append(j)

    for s in secuencias: # for all sequences, ie [ATC, CGN, NNN]
        if 'N' in s: # only if s has N's inside
            posiciones_n = [i for i, c in enumerate(s) if c == 'N']  # save the position of the N

            if len(posiciones_n) == len(s): # if there are only N's, go to the next sequence

              break

            else:
              new_seqs = []
              for h in b: # for every "valid" option
                for u in posiciones_n: # for all positions that store an N
                    if h == u: # when there is an available option to change an N for a "valid" nt

                        new_seq = s.replace(s[h], a[u]) # replace said position for a new nt

                        new_seqs.append(new_seq)

            output.extend(new_seqs)

        else:
            # If there are no N's, append directly to the output. 
            output.append(s)


    return np.unique(output)
```

I believe the main issue is in the logic inside the two for loops, and how I am using replace.

The current output for this example: `["ACN", "TGT", "NNG"]` is this: `['AAG' 'ACT' 'CCG' 'TGT']`. If I'm not wrong, it is replacing every instance of 'N' with the first instance of the list 'b' available. That is why there are two A's and two C', instead of a sequence with 'AC' and another one with 'TG'.

I am not really sure how to fix it, any help is appreciated! If more information is needed please let me know.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What should be the output of `["ACN", "TNT", "NNG"]` ?

Comment: It should be: ['ACT,' 'ACG', 'TCT', 'ACG']. TCG should not be a valid option, due to 'mixing' information from two different sequences: 'ACT' and 'TNT'. I will edit the question and add this example!

Comment: Why `["NNA", "CNN", "NGN"]` should return `["CGA"]`? You're mixing the letters from multiple sequences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try (note: according to your statement, one should not mix from different sequences so `["NNA", "CNN", "NGN"]` shouldn't return `['NNA', 'CNN', 'NGN']` ?):

```py
test_cases = [
    ["ATC", "CGN", "NNN"],
    ["ACG", "TGT", "CAG"],
    ["ATN", "GCN", "GGN"],
    ["ACN", "TGT", "NNG"],
    ["NTA", "GNC", "CGN"],
    ["NNA", "CNN", "NGN"],
    ["ACN", "TNT", "NNG"],
]


def process(lst):
    lst_indices_N = [{i for i, ch in enumerate(v) if ch == "N"} for v in lst]
    lst_indices_non_N = [{i for i, ch in enumerate(v) if ch != "N"} for v in lst]

    out = []

    for i, v in enumerate(lst_indices_N):
        if not v:
            out.append(lst[i])
            continue
        elif v and len(v) == len(lst[i]):
            continue

        should_merge = True

        for j, u in enumerate(lst_indices_non_N):
            if v.issubset(u):
                s = list(lst[i])
                for k in v:
                    s[k] = lst[j][k]
                out.append("".join(s))
                should_merge = False

        if should_merge:
            out.append(lst[i])

    return out


for t in test_cases:
    print("test case :", t)
    print("processed :", process(t))
    print()
```

Prints:

```py
test case : ['ATC', 'CGN', 'NNN']
processed : ['ATC', 'CGC']

test case : ['ACG', 'TGT', 'CAG']
processed : ['ACG', 'TGT', 'CAG']

test case : ['ATN', 'GCN', 'GGN']
processed : ['ATN', 'GCN', 'GGN']

test case : ['ACN', 'TGT', 'NNG']
processed : ['ACT', 'ACG', 'TGT', 'ACG', 'TGG']

test case : ['NTA', 'GNC', 'CGN']
processed : ['GTA', 'CTA', 'GTC', 'GGC', 'CGA', 'CGC']

test case : ['NNA', 'CNN', 'NGN']
processed : ['NNA', 'CNN', 'NGN']

test case : ['ACN', 'TNT', 'NNG']
processed : ['ACT', 'ACG', 'TCT', 'ACG']
```

Comment: Yes! You are right about the last one, sorry, I did not realize that. The answer seems right, thanks a lot!